# Bug in Google Chart Dashboard Using Legend to Filter

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have a dashboard filtered by rangefilter and by clicking on the legend. It works well except when clicking on the first item in the legend. I am not sure what went wrong here.

The working code can be seen in this link : http://jsfiddle.net/hRAhJ/144/

```
var columns = [];
var series = {};
for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
  columns.push(i);
  if (i > 0) {
    series[i - 1] = {};
  }
}
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function() {
  var sel = dash.getSelection();
  // if selection length is 0, we deselected an element
  if (sel.length > 0) {
    // if row is undefined, we clicked on the legend
    if (sel[0].row === null) {
      var col = sel[0].column;
      if (columns[col] == col) {
        // hide the data series
        columns[col] = {
          label: data.getColumnLabel(col),
          type: data.getColumnType(col),
          calc: function() {
            return null;
          }
        };

        // grey out the legend entry
        series[col - 1].color = '#CCCCCC';
      } else {
        // show the data series
        columns[col] = col;
        series[col - 1].color = null;
      }

      // set series option
      chart.setOption('series', series);

      var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
      view.setColumns(columns);
      dash.bind([rangeFilter], [chart]);
      dash.draw(view);
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure what's going on with the data view,
but setting the view directly on the chart wrapper instead,
seems to work ok...

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['controls']
});

function drawChart() {
  var query = new google.visualization.Query("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xUzHqQjFRV3CcCEmsVUezz4hzwHDxPFW15f5Da0xBS0/edit#gid=0&headers=1&tq?range=A1:AA42");
  query.send(handleQueryResponse);
}

function handleQueryResponse(response) {
  var data = response.getDataTable();

  var rangeFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    controlType: 'ChartRangeFilter',
    containerId: 'range_filter_div',
    options: {
      filterColumnIndex: 0,
      ui: {
        chartOptions: {
          height: 50,
          width: 1000, // must be the same in both the chart and the control
          chartArea: {
            width: '70%' // must be the same in both the chart and the control
          }
        },
        chartView: {
          columns: [0, 1]
        }
      }
    },
    state: {
      range: {
        // set the starting range to January 2012
        start: new Date(1940),
        end: new Date(1990)
      }
    }
  });

  var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'LineChart',
    containerId: 'chart_div',
    options: {
      // width and chartArea.width should be the same for the filter and chart
      height: 600,
      width: 1000,
      legend: { textStyle : { fontSize : 12 } },
      chartArea: {
        width: '70%'
      }
    }
  });

  // Create the dashboard
  var dash = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard'));
  // bind the chart to the filter
  dash.bind([rangeFilter], [chart]);
  // draw the dashboard
  dash.draw(data);

  var columns = [];
  var series = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
    columns.push(i);
    if (i > 0) {
      series[i - 1] = {};
    }
  }
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function() {
    var sel = dash.getSelection();
    // if selection length is 0, we deselected an element
    if (sel.length > 0) {
      // if row is undefined, we clicked on the legend
      if (sel[0].row === null) {
        var col = sel[0].column;
        if (columns[col] == col) {
          // hide the data series
          columns[col] = {
            label: data.getColumnLabel(col),
            type: data.getColumnType(col),
            calc: function() {
              return null;
            }
          };

          // grey out the legend entry
          series[col - 1].color = '#CCCCCC';
        } else {
          // show the data series
          columns[col] = col;
          series[col - 1].color = null;
        }

        // set series option & view columns
        chart.setOption('series', series);
        chart.setView({columns: columns});

        dash.draw(data);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="dashboard">
  <div id="chart_div"></div>
  <div id="range_filter_div"></div>
</div>
```